# How can I log an error as if it was uncaught?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

I have a complex JavaScript application where when certain unexpected errors occur, I want to log them for debugging but continue.

How do I log them to the console **so that their stack is accessible in the normal fashion for an uncaught error?**

A uncaught error in the Chrome console normally shows only the error message, and has a disclosure triangle which can be clicked to show the stack trace. This (and any other debugging features Chrome has now or might add in the future for uncaught errors) is what I want.

If I do the obvious `catch (e) { console.log(e); }` or `console.error(e)`, the error object is instead shown in object-inspector fashion — there is a triangle but clicking it shows the *properties of the error object* (so I have to click four more times to get the stack property in a poorly-formatted way). I could log `e.stack`, but that's still missing some standard features.

`setTimeout(function () { throw e; }, 0);` is another option, but confuses debugging because it changes the ordering of messages in the console. (Putting the entire code-which-might-throw in a setTimeout *might* be feasible, but I want to investigate just fixing the logging first.)

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, but if you may, take a look at AngularJS's source, they do basically what you want. Be warned that *it makes debugging in any other browser nearly impossible!*

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(prettyformatstack(e));` instead!

where `prettyformatstack(e)` takes an error returns the string you are looking for.

Comment: You are implicitly proposing that I do `console.log(e.stack)`. This does get the stack, of course, but it does not get the rest of the formatting. I could get closer by using `console.groupCollapsed`, but it would still be not **the standard uncaught-error formatting** — and it won't have any debugging conveniences introduced in future versions of Chrome.

Comment: then just write a function that formats it like you want, that is pretty plain and simple

Comment: **I don't want to to copy browser features, I want to invoke them!** But just logging the stack explicitly is a good backup plan if what I want turns out to be impossible. Thanks for pointing out the possibility.